# Binding Path Syntax for OData Models

Tags: sapui5

Here i am trying to bind an Odata service to fetch the information from the SAP ABAP.

Although I am using relative binding path, I am not able to get the information as expected.

**Controller.js**

```
var oListItem= this.getView().byId("BoMSet");   
oListItem.bindElement("invoice>/ProductHeadSet('12345')/ProductHead2BOM");
```

**View.xml**

```
<List id="BoMSet"
      headerText="BoM">
        <items>
            <ObjectListItem intro="{invoice>Material}"
                            title="{invoice>BomNumber}">
            </ObjectListItem>
        </items>
```

**manifest.json**

```
     "dataSources": {
"invoiceRemote": {
            "uri": "http://abc/sap/opu/odata/SAP/xyz/",
            "type": "OData",
            "settings": {
                "odataVersion": "2.0"
}
}
```

**model**

```
"invoice": {
            "dataSource": "invoiceRemote"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used bindElement on your List so you still need to specify your items binding on your View.

I take it your ProductHeadSet has a list in it which is what you want to display on your UI.

For example, if ProductHeadSet has a list called Products, your view would look like this:

```
<List
    id="BoMSet"
    headerText="BoM"
    items="{
        path: '/Products'
    }">
        <items>
          <ObjectListItem
             intro="{invoice>Material}"
             title="{invoice>BomNumber}">
           </ObjectListItem>
        </items>
</List>
```

You could also take another approach and call bindItems in your controller:

```
var oListItem= this.getView().byId("BoMSet"); 
oListItem.bindItems({
                path : "invoice>/ProductHeadSet('12345')/products", 
                template : new sap.m.StandardListItem({
                    title: "{invoice>BomNumber}",
                    description: "{invoice>Material}"
                })
            });
```

And your view would only contain the List declaration:

```
<List
    id="BoMSet"
    headerText="BoM"
</List>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, my concern was the path : invoice>/ProductHeadSet('12345')/products(here i am routing to another path called "ProductHead2BOM", there i could find the property reference).

Comment: Is your ProductHead2BOM an array ? If not, binding a single element to a list does not make sense.

Comment: well i have found the Solution for that, but right i am kinda frezzed in middle. i have Odata service on the same page with using "TabFilter" element. Now what i need is when i click on the number f.e: listitem"12345" i need to fetch the data of the "products" which is linked to "12345" and navigate me to those informations(BOMnumber, materials).